# Autosize Window with multiple GridPanels

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4.2

I have a modal Window, with a minimum height of 250px and maximum of 600px. Programatically I put 1 or 2 or 3 or infinite GridPanel in it. My problem is that I can't get it working.

If the window has a fit layout, then still it will be 250px high, and the first Grid will fit in completely, if there is another one then it is under it invisible.

If the windows layout is vbox, then it's also 250px high, but at least all the GridPanels are in it visible. The problem with this, that if any of the grids has too many rows, then it will simply put a scrollbar in the grid, but instead of this i would like to expand the grids height to make every row visible, and  expand the windows height also.

Any thoughts?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because there were no ansers I do it myself.
Maybe there is a more automatic way but this is the best I was able to make.
Every time I add a grid to the window I loop through the grids, get their heights, sum them and with the setHeight method I set the window height.